# Create Black holes in Box2D games?

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, box2d

I make simple game using Box2D.

I want to add new feature of Black Holes . Please tell me how to create black holes randomly in my application. Please help me....

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a circular sensor object, that when bodies collide with are given an impulse toward the center of the sensor.

You could also scale the objects the closer they get to the center, and delete them as they hit the center point.